# How to change the folder to be imported in an angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, import, graphql

I'm importing a node module using `import {GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType} from 'graphql';` but it's referencing the wrong folder . Is there any way I can reference the node module 'graphql' instead without having to write the entire path similar to how I reference other node module like `import { ApolloModule } from 'apollo-angular';`?

This is the error im getting:

```
'.../server/graphql/index"' has no exported member 'GraphQLObjectType'
```

I'm trying to reference the node module and not the folder I created.

This is a simplified version of my file structure:

```
.
+-- client
|   +-- app.module.ts
+-- node_modules
+-- server
|   +-- graphql
|   |   +-- mutations
|   |   +-- queries
|   |   +-- types
|   |   +-- index.ts
|   |   +-- app.ts // my server file
+-- package.json
+-- .angular-cli.json
```

Answer (score 0):

There may a better answer, but the easiest and most obvious answer is to rename your `/server/graphql` folder something like `server/gql`